# ¿Cómo se traduce "New Mexico Whiptail Lizard" al español?

Tags: traducción, animales

Quiero traducir el nombre de este lagarto al español, pero no lo encuentro por ninguna página. Desafortunadamente, tampoco la página de Wikipedia para este lagarto esta traducida al español. ¿Hay alguien que lo conozca?

De antemano ¡muchísimas gracias!

[image: New Mexico Whiptail Lizard, fuente: http://www.reptilesofaz.org/Lizards-Subpages/h-a-neomexicana.html]

Comment: "El Lagarto de Neuvo Mexico con cola que látigosar"?

Comment: Bueno, sabemos *lizard = lagarto* y *whip = látigo*, luego *whiptail = cola de látigo* y *whiptail lizard = lagarto cola de látigo*.

Comment: Su nombre científico es "aspidoscelis neomexicana" y el único articulo en español que encuentro es este http://www.parcplace.org/images/stories/YOL/Estado_de_los_Lagartos.pdf donde los llaman Whiptails de Nuevo México. Adhiero a la recomendación de @Ustanak _Lagarto cola de látigo_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cnemidophorus neomexicanus** , o [lagarto de cola látigo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnemidophorus):

> es un género de lagartos que pertenecen a la familia Teiidae, conocidos con el nombre común de ***lagartos de cola látigo*** o el de ***huicos*** en Sonora y Sinaloa...

Notables por ser una de las pocas especies sin machos, es decir que se reproducen por [partenogénesis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RzqI2nl).

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias. Debo de haber sospechado que el nombre fuera una traducción literal del ingles. =P

Comment: En un libro se llama a este especie específicamente como **"el lagarto cola de látigo de Nuevo México"** - `"Es el caso del lagarto cola de látigo de Nuevo México (Cnemidophorus neomexicanus), es una especie de puras hembras que se reproducen sin ninguna contribución genética de un macho. "` - [*Heroes y Villanos de la Medicina...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vbHiKODdd-0C&pg=PA225&dq="Cnemidophorus+neomexicanus"), y en muchos como **"huico de Nuevo México"** - [*Normas oficiales mexicanas en materia ambiental*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WzcSAQAAIAAJ&q="Cnemidophorus").